# Understanding Decompiled Assembly Code

Tags: c, assembly, int32

I'm trying to understand this code from assembly,

```
int32_t phase_5(char * str) {
    int32_t v1 = 0;
    if (strlen(str) != 4) {
        // 0x8049153
        alert_henchmen(5);
        v1 = 0;
        // branch -> 0x80491a6
    }
    while (true) {
        int32_t * v2 = (int32_t *)(4 * v1 + (int32_t)&g2); // 0x8049192_0
        char * v3 = (char *)(v1 + (int32_t)str);
        int32_t v4 = 0;
        int32_t v5 = 0; // 0x01516
        // branch -> 0x8049175
        int32_t v6; // bp+014
        while (true) {
            char v7 = *(char *)(v4 + (int32_t)"4l6aiqhor20x"); // 0x8049188
            v6 = v5;
            if ((int32_t)*v3 == (int32_t)v7) {
                // 0x804918f
                v6 = *v2 == v4 ? 1 : v5;
                // branch -> 0x80491a2
            }
            int32_t v8 = v4 + 1; // 0x80491a2
            if (v8 >= 12) {
                // break -> 0x80491ac
                break;
            }
            v4 = v8;
            v5 = v6;
            // continue -> 0x8049175
        }
        // 0x80491ac
        if (v6 % 256 != 1) {
            // 0x80491b7
            alert_henchmen(5);
            // branch -> 0x80491c3
        }
        int32_t v9 = v1 + 1; // 0x80491c3
        if (v9 >= 4) {
            // break -> 0x80491cd
            break;
        }
        v1 = v9;
        // continue -> 0x80491a6
    }
    // 0x80491cd
    return confirm_phase(5, str);
}
```

and I'm just not sure what this line does:

```
int32_t * v2 = (int32_t *)(4 * v1 + (int32_t)&g2)
```

and also this line:

```
char v7 = *(char *)(v4 + (int32_t)"4l6aiqhor20x")
```

and what does int32_t mean?

Comment: It means cast that value as a 32 bit integer.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Please do not link to C++ documentation for C questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is, but I will try to help in answer, by explaining that when a programmer writes something, there is a purpose to each line that he or she knows about - for example, if they want to write a message, they may call the variable "myMessage". This information is not included in the final result, though. So, a decompiler won't know to call it "myMessage", and will just assign a memory address (denoted by a & reference), or a random variable name (denoted by v's above). With some detailed examination, you can figure out what that part of the code does specifically, but without hints like "myMessage", you may have to process and map out the entire program before really understanding it.

So for the code line:
int32_t * v2 = (int32_t *)(4 * v1 + (int32_t)&g2)

You can only say that it takes 4, multiplies it by v1, and adds it to the address of variable g2. The result is a 32-bit address that is stored in v2. Because there's no reference here that says what g2 even is, then you may start to see the rationale in my answer. Since it's 32 bits (4 bytes), this could explain the multiplication by 4, and maybe v1 is a counter.

Answer (score 0):

`int32_t` is one of the types defined in [`<stdint.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html); it is a 32-bit wide signed integer type with 2's complement representation and no padding bits.

The decompiler seems to take the shortest possible path, without actually understanding how to write idiomatic C code. The code itself might not even be valid **C** as I believe it might not conform to strict aliasing requirements of C.

Here, for example:

```
int32_t * v2 = (int32_t *)(4 * v1 + (int32_t)&g2); // 0x8049192_0
```

The value of the address of `g2` is converted to an `int32_t`; then the value `4 * v1` is added to it; and the resulting integer is cast to a pointer to `int32_t`. This is a contrived way of writing

```
int32_t *v2 = ((int32_t *)&g2) + v1;
```

Or; if `g2` is already declared as an array of `int32_t`, it is sufficient to write

```
int32_t *v2 = g2 + v1;
```

All in all, the code casts the address of `g2` into a pointer to `int32_t`, and then assigns the pointer to *`v1`th* (0-based) `int32_t` in the array of consecutive `int32_t`s, first of which is the one at that pointer, into `v2`.

Again,

```
char v7 = *(char *)(v4 + (int32_t)"4l6aiqhor20x")
```

Is the straightforward - but non-portable code (it doesn't work in 64-bit processors!) for the code

```
char v7 = "4l6aiqhor20x"[v4];
```

i.e. the value of `v4`th character from the string `"4l6aiqhor20x"` is assigned to `v7`.